# UITableView resizes when adding element

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard

I´m working on a IRC client for iPhone and I am having problems with my UITableView.

First I resized the tableview so that a toolbar and the keyboard will fit on the screen as the user is typing a message. Looking like this:

[image: User typing mode]

But the problem is that when the user is done typing and wants to send the message (send to stream and add to the tableview) the tableview is resized and the toolbar is put at the bottom  but the keyboard remain, I do NOT which the textfield to resign first responder, I want to keep the keyboard and toolbar where its at before and after pressing the send button. Looking like this:

[image: Fail mode]

This is some of my code:

-Resizing the windows

```
// Keyboard will show
- (void)keyboardWillShow {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 177)];
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 177, 320, 43)];
    }];    
}

// Keyboard will hide
- (void)keyboardWillHide {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 481)];
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 393, 320, 43)];
    }];    
}
```

-Adding element to the tableview

```
// Retrieve the sender and the message from the input and add it to the data context
- (void)addMessage:(NSString *) input isSender: (BOOL) sender {
    Message *messageToBeAdded = [[Message alloc] init];
    [messageToBeAdded setIsSender:sender];

    NSArray *arr = [input componentsSeparatedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PRIVMSG %@ :",[connection channel]]];
    [messageToBeAdded setMessage:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];

    arr = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"];

    if (sender) {
        [messageToBeAdded setSender:[connection nick]];
    } else {
        NSString *tmp = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
        [messageToBeAdded setSender:[tmp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [tmp length]-1)]];
    }

    [_messageList addObject:messageToBeAdded];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_messageList count]-1 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

I´ve looked everywhere and I´m certain that it has to do with the add part of the tableview. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Thank you!

EDIT:
I have just realized that is has to do with the use of a custom cell. I created a new project and tried to simulate what I have done step-by-step. And everything worked fine up too the point where I used a custom cell with an UILabel. The UILabel was connected to the UITableViewCell class with an outlet and this is where the problem occurred.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

Any thought what could be wrong here?

Comment: I think the question was missunderstood, I do not wish to remove the keyboard upon pressing the send button. Thanks for the responses so far tho!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you have a `UITextField` in your Toolbar. Try...

```
[aTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

... when you handle hitting the the send/return button.

Comment: The thing is I don't want it to resign when sending a message. The user has to tap outside for it to resign (which works fine).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted the keyboard to go away after they sent the message.

Answer (score 1):

The text field controls the keyboard so resignfirstresponder sends a message to the keyboard to remove itself. Does the band move to the bottom of the screen or is removed after the send button is pressed. Either way do what Michael said to do and once the keyboard disappears you will know what happens to the banner. I hope this helps!

Comment: I did that and the toolbar is moved to it's original position as with the tableview. It's like the textfield resigned but the keyboard is still there...

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITextFieldDelegate -

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Or if you have IBOutlet of textField then in 'Keyboard will hide' call resignFirstResponder

```
// Keyboard will hide
- (void)keyboardWillHide {

      [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];

      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
          [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 481)];
      }];

      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
          [self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 393, 320, 43)];
      }];    
}
```